# How to return XML to controller as output parameter

Tags: c#, sql, xml, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to return the results of a query in a sproc to a C# .NET MVC4 controller as a string of XML. As I understand it, you are not allowed to send XML to the controller as an output parameter without first converting it to a varchar. I am having trouble with the syntax to convert a `SELECT` statement that outputs XML using `FOR XML AUTO` to a varchar that can be passed back as an output parameter.

Here is some of the sproc code:

```
set @sql='select StatusId from TestTable where StatusId = 3 FOR XML AUTO'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

This example is not using `sp_executesql correctly, but I just wanted a quick example. How could the result be returned to a controller?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about not being allowed to send XML to the controller; however, making some assumptions about your scenario (because the question is a little vague), I do get output on a brand-new MVC5 project (and I see no reason to believe this wouldn't work in MVC4).

Steps to reproduce:

1) I created a table in SSMS:

```
    use test; -- a testing database I leave lying about
    create table TestTable(StatusId int, SomeStuff nvarchar(max));
```

2) I put some data in that table:

```
    insert into TestTable(StatusId, SomeStuff) values (3, 'foo bar quux');
    insert into TestTable(StatusId, SomeStuff) values (4, 'some other stuff');
```

3) I wrote a proc to get the data; specifically, I wanted to see what happened if I got back more than one result, hence my small divergence from your example sql:

```
    create procedure sp_xmlresult as
    begin
        declare @sql nvarchar(max);
        set @sql='select * from TestTable where StatusId in(3,4) FOR XML AUTO, ROOT(''results'')'

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
    end;
```

3) In my MVC HomeController, I add some code like so:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = "localhost";
        builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        builder.InitialCatalog = "test";
        XDocument doc = null;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "exec sp_xmlresult";
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                        doc = XDocument.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        return View(doc);
    }
```

4) Now, I want to see what I get out: I set my Index.cshtml in the Home folder to use XDocument as the model and drop the escaped string representation right there:

```
   @model System.Xml.Linq.XDocument
   ...
   @{ Write(Model.ToString()); }
```

and I see this output in my page:
       <results> <TestTable StatusId="3" SomeStuff="foo bar quux" /> <TestTable StatusId="4" SomeStuff="some other stuff" /> </results>

What is of particular interest is that you'd probably want to include the

```
, ROOT(''results'')'
```

part of the proc I outline above -- otherwise SQL Server gives back a document with one node per result and no root node, so XDocument has a bad day parsing that.

I'd imagine that a more realistic project would be doing something interesting with the XML in the Index() action, but I was all out of imagination by this point. Hope this helps.